# Python binary tree traversal - Node object with a defined left/right attribute is not accessible

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am brushing up on my coding skills and started LeetCode questions a few weeks ago. So far so good except for this error I cannot seem to debug

**Question:** Given the roots of two binary trees p and q, write a function to check if they are the same or not.
Two binary trees are considered the same if they are structurally identical, and the nodes have the same value

**Approach:** Since the tree's in question are binary trees, I opted to use a binary tree traversal method (in-order). If we can traverse the tree and store its values as they appear in an array, then two equal binary trees will have the same array provided that the traversal method used is the same on both trees.

My code for this question is below, but I am not sure why I am getting an error when trying to access the left sub-tree in my 'in_order' method. The second 'if' condition is giving me an error: **'Type int does not have attribute 'left''**

This is confusing me, because when I call my method 'in_order':

```
def isSameTree(self, p: TreeNode, q: TreeNode) -> bool:
        self.in_order(p)
```

I am passing a TreeNode object (p) which *SHOULD* have a left attribute (even if it is None), why/how is the interpreter turning 'p' a tree node object, into an 'int'?

I am not looking for a new method to solve this question, rather why/how this error is occurring?

Thank you for taking the time to read through.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def in_order(self, tree, result=None):
        if result is None:
            result = []
        if tree.left:
            result.append(tree.left.val)
            self.in_order(tree.left.val, result)
        result.append(tree.val)
        if tree.right:
            result.append(tree.right.val)
            self.in_order(tree.right.val, result)
        return result
    
    def isSameTree(self, p: TreeNode, q: TreeNode) -> bool:
        self.in_order(p)
```

Full Error trace:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'left'
    if tree.left:
Line 11 in in_order (Solution.py)
    self.in_order(tree.left.val, result)
Line 13 in in_order (Solution.py)
    self.in_order(p)
Line 24 in isSameTree (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().isSameTree(param_1, param_2)
Line 52 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 63 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: You are calling `in_order()` recursively with the node value `tree.left.val`, rather than the subtree `tree.left`.  (And the same for the right side, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.in_order(tree.left.val, result)`
This line is the problem because `tree.left.val` is not a Node. It is an int value in this case.

Comment: Yes you are right! Thanks